# Add legend with color and range in R

Tags: r, colors, legend

The following example code produces a color dot graph according to the values of `a` :

```
a <- sample(1:100)
rbPal <- colorRampPalette(c('red','blue'))
b <- rbPal(10)[as.numeric(cut(a,breaks = 10))]
plot(a,col=b,pch=16)
```

I would like to add a legend to this graph indicating which range of values the colors refer to. 
Something like:

```
 "#C60038" - [20.7 - 30.7]
 "#5500AA" - [60.4 - 70.3]
```

(the above color code are the colored dots).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can save `cut()` levels as separate variable with function `levels()`. With function `gsub()` you can replace `,` with `-` and `(` with `[`. Then in function `legend()` provide position of legend, variable `cuts` to use as labels, `col=rbPal(10)` will use the same 10 colors in legend and `pch=16` will make filled dots.

```
cuts<-levels(cut(a,breaks = 10))
cuts<-gsub(","," - ",cuts)
cuts<-gsub("\\(","[",cuts)
cuts
 [1] "[0.901 - 10.8]" "[10.8 - 20.7]"  "[20.7 - 30.7]"  "[30.7 - 40.6]"  "[40.6 - 50.5]"  "[50.5 - 60.4]"  "[60.4 - 70.3]" 
 [8] "[70.3 - 80.3]"  "[80.3 - 90.2]"  "[90.2 - 100]"  
plot(a,col=b,pch=16)
legend("top",cuts,col=rbPal(10),pch=16)
```

[image]

Comment: I already managed to do this but I really didn't like the format so much. I would like to have both square brackets and `-` in place of comma. Any Idea?

Comment: Didn't think about using `gsub`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to produce the exact legend you describe, you can use `legend` this way :

```
a <- sample(1:100)
rbPal <- colorRampPalette(c('red','blue'))
b <- rbPal(10)[as.numeric(cut(a,breaks = 10))]
plot(a,col=b,pch=16)
legend('topright', legend=c("[20.7 - 30.7]", "[60.4 - 70.3]"), col=c("#C60038","#5500AA"), pch=16)
```

Which would give :

[image]

I'd recommend you to take a look at `ggplot2`, which allows to produce great graphs while creating legends automatically, for example :

```
x <- sample(1:100)
y <- sample(1:100)
fact <- runif(100)
df <- data.frame(x,y,fact)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x,y=y,col=fact)) + geom_point()
```

[image]