# How to use color ranges/bins/brackets in ggplot legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I need to show the lower and upper bound of each color in the legend. I feel like there should be an easy ggplot function to do this, but I haven't been able to find one. Here's a cheap workaround that isn't great (numbers need to be shifted):

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = runif(100),
  y = runif(100),
  z1 = rnorm(100)
)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = z1)) +
  scale_colour_steps(n.breaks=5, labels = sort(unique(cut(df$y,5)), decreasing = T))
```

[image: sample plot]

This post asks the same question and gets an answer in Base R:

[Add legend with color and range in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828058/add-legend-with-color-and-range-in-r)

Let me know if there is a better way to do this in ggplot.

Comment: Set the breaks you want before plotting using `cut`.